# Spark streaming elasticsearch dependencies

Tags: scala, twitter, elasticsearch, streaming, apache-spark

Im trying Spark & Elasticsearch integration in scala as described in [Elasticsearch Guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html)

I  have problems with dependencies when compiling :

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: cascading#ing-local;2.5.6: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: clj-time#clj-time;0.4.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: compojure#compojure;1.1.3: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: hiccup#hiccup;0.3.6: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: ring#ring-devel;0.3.11: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: ring#ring-jetty-adapter;0.3.11: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.twitter#carbonite;1.4.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: cascading#cascading-hadoop;2.5.6: not found
[error] Total time: 86 s, completed 19 nov. 2014 08:42:58
```

My build.sbt file look like this

```
name := "twitter-sparkstreaming-elasticsearch"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

// additional libraries
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.1.0",
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop" % "2.1.0"
)
```

Help?
thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cascading and its dependencies are not available in Maven central but in their own repo (which es-hadoop cannot specify through its pom).

I resolved the problem by using [elasticsearch-spark_2.10](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark_2.10/2.1.0.Beta2)

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/install.html

Answer (score 7):

Sbt can't resolve some dependencies because they aren't part of the Maven repository.
However, you can find them on [clojars](https://clojars.org/) and [conjars](http://conjars.org/).
You need to add the following lines so sbt can resolve them:

```
resolvers += "clojars" at "https://clojars.org/repo"
resolvers += "conjars" at "http://conjars.org/repo"
```

Also, the dependency elasticsearch-hadoop "2.1.0" doesn't exist (yet ?), you should use "2.1.0.Beta4" (or whatever the latest version is when you read this)

Your sbt file should look like this:

```
name := "twitter-sparkstreaming-elasticsearch"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.1.0",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.1.0",
    "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop" % "2.1.0.Beta4"
)

resolvers += "clojars" at "https://clojars.org/repo"
resolvers += "conjars" at "http://conjars.org/repo"
```

This has been tested (with spark-core 1.3.1 and without spark-streaming but it should work for you).
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

That is because cascading and its dependencies are not in Maven.
You have to add resolvers to get them

Add this line to your build.sbt

```
resolvers += "conjars.org" at "http://conjars.org/repo"
```

Your build.sbt should look like this:

```
name := "twitter-sparkstreaming-elasticsearch"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

// additional libraries
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.1.0",
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop" % "2.1.0"
)

resolvers += "conjars.org" at "http://conjars.org/repo"
```

NOTE: This issue has been raised and closed here https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/304 with the same solution as above

Answer (score 0):

`"org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop" % "2.1.0"` is not available yet. You can use `"org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop" % "2.1.0.Beta2"`

Check here:

- http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/2.1.0.Beta2

**EDIT1**

Even after using `"org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop" % "2.1.0.Beta2"` I am also getting the same error:

```
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: cascading#cascading-local;2.5.6: not found
[warn]  :: clj-time#clj-time;0.4.1: not found
[warn]  :: compojure#compojure;1.1.3: not found
[warn]  :: hiccup#hiccup;0.3.6: not found
[warn]  :: ring#ring-devel;0.3.11: not found
[warn]  :: ring#ring-jetty-adapter;0.3.11: not found
[warn]  :: com.twitter#carbonite;1.4.0: not found
[warn]  :: cascading#cascading-hadoop;2.5.6: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: cascading#cascading-local;2.5.6: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: clj-time#clj-time;0.4.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: compojure#compojure;1.1.3: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: hiccup#hiccup;0.3.6: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: ring#ring-devel;0.3.11: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: ring#ring-jetty-adapter;0.3.11: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.twitter#carbonite;1.4.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: cascading#cascading-hadoop;2.5.6: not found
[error] Total time: 41 s, completed Nov 19, 2014 8:44:04 PM
```

My `build.sbt` looks like this

```
name := "twitter-sparkstreaming-elasticsearch"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

// additional libraries
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.1.0",
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop" % "2.1.0.Beta2",
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop-cascading" % "2.1.0.Beta2"
)

resolvers += "sonatype-oss" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

Answer (score 0):

For Spark only support, you can use the minimalistic binary.
Add the following to `libraryDependencies` in `build.sbt`

```
"org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-spark_2.10" % "2.1.0.Beta3"
```

*Note: '2.10' refers to the compatible Scala version!*

And remove

```
"org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop" % "2.1.0.Beta3"
```

This will avoid the unresolved deps listed in the question.